# Break string in different parts

Tags: php

How do I break the value of address in different parts?

eg: Jl. Work No. 181 RT 006 RW 011 Exod. Sukabungah Kec. Sukajadi city Bandung

be:

```
$address = "Jln. Suka cita No 1, RT 001 RW 002 Kota Bandung";
```

to :

```
$jln = "suka cita no 1 ";
$rt = "001";
$rw = "002";
$kota = "bandung";
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: break the variable
from : $adress = "Jln. Suka cita No 1, RT 001 RW 002 Kota Bandung"
to :
$jln = suka cita no 1
$rt = 001
$rw = 002
$kota = bandung

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegEx is the tool for pulling out parts of specifically structured strings... But ONLY if you can rely on it being in the expected format.

```
$address = "Jln. Suka cita No 1, RT 001 RW 002 Kota Bandung";

// Match everything from the start to the first comma
preg_match('/^([^,]+),/', $address, $matches );
$jln = $matches[1];

// Match a row of digits appearing atter " RT "
preg_match('/ RT (\d+) /', $address, $matches);
$rt = $matches[1];

// Match a row of digits appearing after " RW "
preg_match('/ RW (\d+) /', $address, $matches);
$rw = $matches[1];

// Match everything from the string "Kota " to the end of line
preg_match('/Kota (.+)$/', $address, $matches );
$kota = $matches[1];
```

Code not been tested because I am writing this answer from my phone but it will be something very similar to this.

Comment: wah, very thanks its work

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to achieve this if you structure the data in your database in a suitable manner. Try something like this.

Firstly you will need to store the data in the database in the structure that you will need it in. You will need to create a table with rows in it a little like this:

```
jln
rt
rw
kota
```

The SQL query to achieve this will look something like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `jln` text NOT NULL,
  `rt` text NOT NULL,
  `rw` text NOT NULL,
  `kota` text NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `test` (`jln`, `rt`, `rw`, `kota`) VALUES
('suka cita no 1', '001', '002', 'bandung');
```

Query the database to pull out the values

```
// Open database
$m_db = new mysqli('your_hostname', 'your_username'], 'your_password', 'your_db_name']);

// Check for errors
if ($m_db->connect_errno > 0) {
   trigger_error('Unable to connect to database [' . $m_db->connect_error . 
   ']', E_USER_ERROR); 
}

// Query the database
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM test");

// Check that there is a valid result
$data = array();
if ($result) {
   // Put all of the results into an array
   while ($result_row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $data[] = $result_row;
   }

   // Free the database handle
   $result->free();
}

// Example code to display output for debugging
foreach ($data AS $values) {
   print_r($values);
}
```

This will put your values into an array as follows:

```
$values[0]['jln'] = 'suka cita no 1'
$values[0]['rt'] = '001'
$values[0]['rw'] = '002'
$values[0]['kota'] = 'bandung'
```

Comment: if have "while" why we use "foreach" again ?
i read from w3school just use while its clear

Comment: The foreach section is just an example to show you what data the code will output.